# set "response_mode and code_challenge_methods_supported

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm using the asgardeo library for tomcat and i was wondering if there was a possibility to set the parameter "code_challenge_methods_supported" and "response_mode" by config file properties.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `additionalParamsForAuthorizeEndpoint` property to set these parameters. For more information, you can refer to: https://github.com/asgardeo/asgardeo-tomcat-oidc-agent/blob/master/io.asgardeo.tomcat.oidc.sample/src/main/resources/configuration-catalog.md#additional-parameters-for-authorize-endpoint